# Fluent Nhibernate - Is it possible to get more than one related entities of an entity?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to get more than one related entities of an entity? Say for example I have a class Album and it has two properties namely Artist and Genre.... How can I get an Album with its related artist and genre? Thanks in advance :p

Answer (score 0):

as simple as

```
var albums = session.Query<Album>()
    .Where(a => <whatever>)
    .Fetch(a => a.Artist)
    .Fetch(a => a.Genre)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: or you could use projection